# How to block particular app screen or app component from taking screenshot or screen recording in react native app

Tags: react-native, screenshot

I want to hide password field in the login screen in the screenshot or screen recording. the password field is automatically hidden if the show button is turned off(`secureTextEntry`=true). but if the show button in the password field is turned on, the password value in field will be visible in the screenshot (`secureTextEntry`=false).

I think for android, this package can do the job : [react-native-flag-secure-android](https://github.com/kristiansorens/react-native-flag-secure-android)

What do to for ios ?